# SonarQube : TypeScript baseUrl and relative paths configuration => issue “Dependencies should be explicit” (typescript:S4328)

Tags: typescript, sonarqube

## Context

- ALM used : **Azure DevOps**
- CI system used : **Azure DevOps**
- Scanner command used when applicable (private details masked) :

```
  - task: SonarCloudPrepare@1
    inputs:
      SonarCloud: 'SonarCloud-Clement'
      organization: 'assoconnect'
      scannerMode: 'CLI'
      configMode: 'manual'
      cliProjectKey: 'assoconnect_frontend'
      cliProjectName: 'frontend'
      cliProjectVersion: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
      cliSources: 'src'
      extraProperties: |
        sonar.tests=src
        sonar.test.inclusions=**/__tests__/**
        sonar.coverage.exclusions=src/pages/**
        sonar.junit.reportPaths=junit.xml
        sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
        sonar.typescript.tsconfigPath=tsconfig.json
    displayName: 'Prepare SonarQube analysis'

  - task: SonarCloudAnalyze@1
    displayName: 'Run SonarQube analysis'

  - task: SonarCloudPublish@1
    inputs:
      pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
    displayName: 'Publish SonarQube analysis result'
```

- Languages of the repository : **TypeScript**

## Problem observed

For all our `imports` in `.tsx` files , we have instances of the "*Dependencies should be explicit (typescript:S4328)*" issue.

We have configured a `baseUrl` (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#base-url) in our `tsconfig.json` file so that we don't have to deal with relative paths.
WebStorm seems OK with this config and the linter doesn't show any message.
But in Sonar, when we import a module, since there is no `./` prepending, it thinks it is an external module and looks for it in the dependencies.

## Example

- our layout is :

```
src/
|___pages/
|   |___Index/
|       |___index.tsx
|       |___type.tsx
|___App.tsx
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

- files contents

```
// package.json
// nothing path-related, only external dependencies
...
```

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
...
```

```js
// src/App.tsx
...
import Index from 'pages/Index' // => ISSUE : Dependencies should be explicit (typescript:S4328)
...
```

```js
// src/pages/Index/index.tsx
...
import * as Type from './type' // => OK, NO ISSUES
...
import { StoreContext } from 'store' // => ISSUE : Dependencies should be explicit (typescript:S4328)
...
export default () => (
...
```

Comment: FYI : https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/issues/1929

Answer (score 1):

[image]

you can try to add specific path in `sonar.sources` like this:

```
// in my tsconfig
"paths": {
      "src": [
        "./src/*"
      ],
    },

// in my sonar-project.properties
sonar.sources=src/components,src/navigation,src/screens,src/store,src/types,src/utils
```

it works for me, in sonar scan report 'dependency should be explicit' issues are removed